# If $f:D\to D$ is holomorphic, and has two distinct fixed points, then $f$ is identity

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

A problem in Mr.Stein's Complex analysis,page 250, ex12（a）,how to prove :$f:D\rightarrow D$ is holomorphic,and has two distinct fixed points,then  f is identity.

Comment: What is $D$ and what are your ideas?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier  sorry， my mistakes，D is the unit disc.

Comment: (First Google hit for “unit disk holomorphic two fixed points” ...)